# zend framwork 2: How to create action in specific controller in specific action

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using zftool to create action using zendframework version 2 but i am getting error.

here is my command :

```
C:\>php zftool.phar create action list User user d:\xampp\htdocs\zf2dummy
```

but i am getting following error:

```
Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided
```

My module name is     : user
My controller name is : User
and my action name is : list

where i am going wrong.help please. thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried php zftool.phar create action list UserController user d:\xampp\htdocs\zf2dummy ?

Comment: @crushedGrass:  yes i have tried that too

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am running into the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the name of the method? `list` is a PHP predefined function and I have similar problem with CodeIgniter, where I couldn't define a method named this way.